# Run Scheme Program in Sublime Text Ubuntu

Tags: scheme, sublimetext3

I tried to run a program using scheme syntax but I couldn't. I got this ...

```
  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gsi'
  [cmd: ['gsi', '-:d-', '/home/salinas/Documents/LP/scheme.scm']]
  [dir: /home/salinas/Documents/LP]
  [path: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" :/home/salinas/.rvm/bin]
  [Finished]
```

Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: It appears that your Sublime Text was set up to use Gambit as the implementation. Do you have Gambit installed? If you're using a different Scheme implementation, the command will have to be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the configured Scheme environment (Gambit) you need to install it. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get intall gambc
```

Then `gsi` should be available.

If it doesn't work because the package was not found you may need to [enable universe repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/148653/83681) and try again.

Comment: In arch-based distributions the package is named `gambit-c`